# How to extend style using emotion-styled?

Tags: css, reactjs, emotion

I would like to pass style to two styled component using emotion.

I've tried like this, but ${commonStyle} doesn't inherit to styled.a and styled.span:

```js
const commonStyle = css`
  color: #000;
  font-size: 1.6rem;
`;

const commonLink = styled.a`
  ${commonStyle}
`;

const whiteLink = styled.span`
  ${commonStyle}
  color: #fff;
`;
```

How can I extend css using emotion?

Answer (score 0):

I have came across a solution. Instead of inheriting **commonStyle** as the first property in **commonLink** and **whiteLink**, inherit it as the last property of the both **commonLink** and **whiteLink**.

Look at the code below, I am inheriting **commonStyle** styles into **Child** component and its working fine.

```
import styled from '@emotion/styled'
import {css} from '@emotion/css'

const commonStyle = css`
color: purple;
`
const Child = styled.div`
font-size: 1.6rem;
${commonStyle}

`

const Parent = styled.div`
  ${Child} {
    color: green;
  }
`

render(
  <div>
    <Parent>
      <Child>Green</Child>
    </Parent>
    <Child>Purple</Child>
  </div>
)
```

[image: inheriting commonStyle in 2 components]

Comment: Thanks, but it not worked on me. Also your nested style returned error of `Component selectors can only be used in conjunction with @emotion/babel-plugin.` I'm using emotion v11.